# MongoDB Rearrange items in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a model which has an array of items. The order of the items in the array is important:

```
Model {
  items: [{item1}, {item2}, {item3}]
}
```

The items don't have any attribute in them that allows them to be sorted, but their order in the array is what determines their 'order'.

How can I reorder this nested array? For example rearrange it to:

```
Model {
  items: [{item2}, {item1}, {item3}]
}
```

My user operations are only limited to swaps, so I'm okay with something like this. Am I limited to `$push` and `$pull`s?

Also, all of the items are very big, so I'll probably flatten the items and only store item ids in the items array, but that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Are you considering creating a collection of items ?

Comment: Do you want to perform sort operation/

Comment: @L.Meyer Even if it they were a collection, I'd still have to store the document ids in my array. How would I be able to rearrange them?

Comment: For example, you could use an object with indexes : `{ '1': item2._id, '2': item1._id, '3': item3._id }`, when you want to swap you only have to change the ids. If so, keep the size updated in your object.

Comment: @L.Meyer That's an interesting approach but that would unfortunately change my data model, and I'm already using array operations in other parts of my app.